# make RandomForestClassifier predict as integers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I'm using `RandomForestClassifier` on an online competition.
When I submit my model it says that the output must be integers only.
The problem is that when I run my model on my validation set it seems okay.
Is there a way to make sure that the output of `RandomForestClassifier` is integers?
I only submit the model, and therefore I don't have a clue where the problem comes from

Comment: Have you tried either the [numpy `astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) or the [pandas `astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) methods passing them the `int` type to do the conversion?

Comment: The problem is that I pass the model into the competition and it gives me that error that the output must be integers. I therefore can't use `astype` on the competition side after it uses my model on their hidden data. Thank you for the response @hume

Comment: You have to make sure that your labels (y values) have `astype(int)` called on them before training the model

Comment: Sure I did. Moreover while using the validation set on my side it looks fine. I have no idea why when I submit the model it goes wrong on their hidden data unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Classifiers in scikit learn will use the same datatype as the labels they were trained with when you call the `predict` method using them.

Without more of a sample of your code and the process, it's impossible to tell why you are not seeing this behavior.

For example, you could accidentally be calling `predict_proba` which will return float probabilities for each class. Or, it could be that you save your predictions to a CSV and then they are loaded, and it infers a new datatype.

If your model looks like the below, then it is likely a bug in whatever system you are submitting to.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

clf.fit(
    np.random.random(size=(7, 3)),
    np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]).astype(int)
)
#> RandomForestClassifier()

# predict predicts integers
clf.predict(np.random.random(size=(7, 3)))
#> array([2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2])

clf.fit(
    np.random.random(size=(7, 3)),
    np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'])
)
#> RandomForestClassifier()

# predict predicts strings
clf.predict(np.random.random(size=(7, 3)))
#> array(['b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```